# How to create a progress bar with labels for completed progress and remaining progress written in it?

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image]

I want to create something like this in **HTML / CSS** and for dynamic interaction, I will use Angular to pass width. 
I know about how can I pass an attribute dynamically with ngStyle in angular. The part where I have no clue is **purely HTML / CSS**.
Please help me out. Suggest any changes I have to do in question description if required.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/49du0qay/ hope this helps u

Comment: @Ibrahimshaikh, you can check my answer

Comment: @BhavinSolanki yes your answer is correct

Comment: @Ibrahimshaikh Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple idea using one element where you can easily control the width of the progress using CSS variable.

*I made the example without the text to highlight the important parts (see below for an example with text)*

```css
.box {
  width:400px;
  height:100px;
  margin:5px;
  border-radius:10px;
  background:
    linear-gradient(red,red) left/var(--p,200px) 100%,
    linear-gradient(to bottom left,transparent 49.8%,red 50%) var(--p,200px) 0/ 30px 50%,
    linear-gradient(to top left,transparent 49.8%,red 50%) var(--p,200px) 100%/ 30px 50%,
    blue;
    
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
</div>
<div class="box" style="--p:100px">
</div>
<div class="box" style="--p:300px">
</div>
```

Example with text:

```css
.box {
  width:400px;
  height:100px;
  margin:5px;
  border-radius:10px;
  background:
    linear-gradient(red,red) left/var(--p,200px) 100%,
    linear-gradient(to bottom left,transparent 49.8%,red 50%) var(--p,200px) 0/ 30px 50%,
    linear-gradient(to top left,transparent 49.8%,red 50%) var(--p,200px) 100%/ 30px 50%,
    blue;
    
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-between;
  align-items:center;
  font-size:1.3em;
  color:#fff;
}
p {
 padding:0 10px;
 text-align:right;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
<p>Used<br> 200.00</p>
<p>Cash limit<br> 2000.00</p>
</div>
<div class="box" style="--p:100px">
<p>Used<br> 200.00</p>
<p>Cash limit<br> 2000.00</p>
</div>
<div class="box" style="--p:280px">
<p>Used<br> 200.00</p>
<p>Cash limit<br> 2000.00</p>
</div>
```

Comment: When you add text, it is not working well

Comment: @BhavinSolanki if you add the text correctly it will work well ;) .. it's a div with background, I don't see that adding text will create any issue

Comment: @BhavinSolanki added the text anyway, you can check the update

Comment: Thanks a lot @TemaniAfif

Answer (score -1):

There are multiple approaches:

1. Create at least two `<div>` items. The first one would be 100% width with text-align center and a black/white background. Inside this, place another `<div>` to show percent complete/marquee (with appropriate width and background). The outer div contains the text to be displayed. You may need another outer `<div>` to act as a wrapper.

`<div id="MyProgress" class="progressbar">
  <div class="progress-inner">Your text here</div>
</div>`

2. You might want to look at [how Bootstrap does its progress bars](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/progress/) or
3. use the [HTML5 `<progress>` element with CSS](https://css-tricks.com/html5-progress-element/#article-header-id-6) updated by JS:<sup>1</sup>

`progress[value]::-webkit-progress-value::before {
  content: '80%'; // What you want to update
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: -125%;
}`

---

1. This might only work for WebKit browsers, according to the source

Comment: Agi, you can check answer which is pure css and html

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following style to get your desire output.

You have to change `width` in following two `class` :

```
#balance .used,
#balance .used:hover{
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 80%;
}

#balance .used-limit{
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 75%;
}
```

**Here is the code**

```css
ul{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
#balance{
  background: #E1ECF4;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #E1ECF4 #E1ECF4 #E1ECF4;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}

#balance li{
  float: left;
}

#balance a{
  padding: .7em 1em .7em 2em;
  float: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFF;
  position: relative;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.5);
  background-color: #697193;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #697193, #697193);  
}

#balance li:first-child a{
  padding-left: 1em;
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
}

#balance a:hover{
  background: #697193;
}

#balance a::after,
#balance a::before{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0%;
  border-top: 3.4em solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 3.4em solid transparent;
  border-left: 1em solid;
  right: -1em;
}

#balance a::after{ 
  z-index: 2;
  border-left-color: #697193;  
}

#balance a::before{
  border-left-color: #697193;  
  right: -1.0em;
  z-index: 1; 
}

#balance a:hover::after{
  border-left-color: #697193;
}

#balance .limit,
#balance .limit:hover{
  font-weight: bold;
  background: none;
  color :#000;
}

#balance .used,
#balance .used:hover{
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 80%;
}

#balance .used-limit{
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 75%;
}
#balance .limit::after,
#balance .limit::before{
  content: normal;  
}
```

```html
<ul id="balance">
    <li class="used-limit"><a href="" class="used"><p>Used</p><p>250.00</p></a></li>
    <li><a href="" class="limit"><p>Cash Limit</p><p>300.00</p></a></li>
</ul>
```